# Can we sort to keep a particular letter at top and rest alphabetically?

Tags: java, sorting, kotlin, comparator

I have an array like this:

```
"Turkish 1"
"Indonesian 1"
"Malay 2"
"Indonesian 3"
"Yiddish 1"
"Urdu 2"
"Malay 1"
"Indonesian 2"
"Urdu 1"
```

And I want to sort it like this:

```
"Urdu 1"
"Urdu 2"
"Indonesian 1"
"Indonesian 2"
"Indonesian 3"
"Malay 1"
"Malay 2"
"Turkish 1"
"Yiddish 1"
```

Note that items starting from "U" are at the top and the rest of them are alphabetically sorted. How can I achieve this using some sorting algo in Java or Kotlin?

Right now, I only know to loop over the list and put items starting from U to top of the list.

Also, if it possible even in Sqlite, please share that too.

Thanks.

Comment: Not without a special hardcoded logic or a separate sorting attribute.

Comment: Yes, that is possible in Java/Kotlin. Yes, there a `Comparator` code that can be used to achieve this sorting. Now read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: *"items starting from "U""* Do you mean strings starting *with* an uppercase `U`? Or does *from* `U` mean that any string starting with `U` - `Z` are sorted first, but still alphabetically relative to each other?

Comment: @Andreas please check my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to apply a high-level sort override, is to derive an integer value from the override condition, then sort by that first.

In Java:

```java
String[] strings = {
        "Turkish 1",
        "Indonesian 1",
        "Malay 2",
        "Indonesian 3",
        "Yiddish 1",
        "Urdu 2",
        "Malay 1",
        "Indonesian 2",
        "Urdu 1" };
Arrays.sort(strings, Comparator.comparingInt((String s) -> s.startsWith("U") ? 0 : 1)
                               .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
```

*Output*

```
[Urdu 1, Urdu 2, Indonesian 1, Indonesian 2, Indonesian 3, Malay 1, Malay 2, Turkish 1, Yiddish 1]
```

In SQL:

```sql
SELECT description
FROM mytable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN description LIKE 'U%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       , description
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, one approach would be to split into two lists, sort each, and join them:

```
val strings = listOf("Turkish 1", "Indonesian 1", "Malay 2", "Indonesian 3",
                     "Yiddish 1", "Urdu 2", "Malay 1", "Indonesian 2", "Urdu 1")
val result = strings.partition{ it.startsWith("U") }
                    .run{ first.sorted() + second.sorted() }
println(result)
```